# Fixing Apache Struts XSS vulnerability

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, redhat

A recent network scan revealed the following vulnerability: Apache Struts s:a / s:url Tag href Element XSS. Here is a link with more info about this vulnerability: http://osvdb.org/show/osvdb/54122

I would like to patch this vulnerability but everything I have read says that you need to update the struts package. However, in my case, this package is not installed.

I have Redhat Enterprise Linux 5 with Apache 2.2.3. Is struts bundled in there? How can I patch this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Struts definitely isn't bundled in there - it's a Java library.  Is the content you're running behind Apache running Java code?

If not, it's a false positive (and a fairly hilarious one at that).

Comment: ok thanks for confirming my suspicion...i guess ill go back and see why we would have gotten a false positive. thanks!